# DirectX 11 Transparency Issue

Tags: c++, directx, transparency, directx-11

I have a png file with a transparent background.

When i draw the image the transparency works.

[image]

as long as there is no other transparent image in front of it as seen below.

[image]

What changes do i need to make to my transparency code to solve this issue?

Depth stencil code:

```
// Initialize the description of the depth buffer.
ZeroMemory(&depthBufferDesc, sizeof(depthBufferDesc));

// Set up the description of the depth buffer.
depthBufferDesc.Width = screenWidth;
depthBufferDesc.Height = screenHeight;
depthBufferDesc.MipLevels = 1;
depthBufferDesc.ArraySize = 1;
depthBufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
depthBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
depthBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
depthBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
depthBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

// Create the texture for the depth buffer using the filled out description.
result = m_device->CreateTexture2D(&depthBufferDesc, NULL, &m_depthStencilBuffer);
Error::ErrorCheck(result, TEXT("m_device->CreateTexture2D()"));

// Initialize the description of the stencil state.
ZeroMemory(&depthStencilDesc, sizeof(depthStencilDesc));

// Set up the description of the stencil state.
depthStencilDesc.DepthEnable = true;
depthStencilDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
depthStencilDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;

depthStencilDesc.StencilEnable = true;
depthStencilDesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
depthStencilDesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;

// Stencil operations if pixel is front-facing.
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

// Stencil operations if pixel is back-facing.
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

// Create the depth stencil state.
result = m_device->CreateDepthStencilState(&depthStencilDesc, &m_depthStencilState);
Error::ErrorCheck(result, TEXT("m_device->CreateDepthStencilState()"));

// Set the depth stencil state.
m_deviceContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(m_depthStencilState, 0);

// Initailze the depth stencil view.
ZeroMemory(&depthStencilViewDesc, sizeof(depthStencilViewDesc));

// Set up the depth stencil view description.
depthStencilViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
depthStencilViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
depthStencilViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

// Create the depth stencil view.
result = m_device->CreateDepthStencilView(m_depthStencilBuffer, &depthStencilViewDesc, &m_depthStencilView);
Error::ErrorCheck(result, TEXT("m_device->CreateDepthStencilView()"));

// Bind the render target view and depth stencil buffer to the output render pipeline.
m_deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_renderTargetView, m_depthStencilView);
```

Transparency code:

```
//Setup Blend State for transperency
D3D11_BLEND_DESC BlendStateDescription;
ZeroMemory(&BlendStateDescription, sizeof(D3D11_BLEND_DESC));

ID3D11BlendState* blend;

BlendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].BlendEnable = TRUE;
BlendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;
BlendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlend = D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;

BlendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].DestBlend = D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
BlendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_INV_DEST_ALPHA;
BlendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].DestBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
BlendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].BlendOp = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
BlendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].BlendOpAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;

m_device->CreateBlendState(&BlendStateDescription, &blend);
float blendFactor[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
UINT sampleMask = 0xffffffff;

m_deviceContext->OMSetBlendState(blend, blendFactor, sampleMask);
```

Comment: Are you sure the transparency works in the first case? It could be the case that the transparent parts of the png happen to match your clear colour (they're both white).

Comment: I am, if i change the background the image is still transparent :)

Comment: Does by any chance have a depth buffer, write to it and test it in you depth stencil states ?

Comment: I attached the depth buffer code, both this and the blend state code are ran once during setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. Was in the depth buffer. Just a simple change depthStencilDesc.DepthFunc from D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS  to   D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS_EQUAL.

Found the answer here, follow link for more detailed description:
[Detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24864948/transparency-on-two-rectangles-in-directx-one-behind-another-i-see-the-backgr)

Comment: The problem is not the depth buffer state; the problem is that you're modifying the depth buffer at all when rendering transparency.  Switching to `LESS_EQUAL` might have solved your immediate problem but you're wasting bandwidth and will probably run into further issues down the road if you try to do anything more interesting than render flat images in the same plane.  As the answer you linked to recommends, you should probably just turn off depth altogether, and render transparent objects back to front.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Makes sense why i shouldn't have a depth buffer enabled. But im not 100% sure what you mean when you say "render transparent objects back to front". Can you explain this further in more detail so i can understand?

Comment: The only way to correctly render transparent objects to a single render target is to draw them from furthest to nearest relative to the camera (i.e. back to front relative to the viewport).  There are advanced techniques such as order-independent transparency but they usually require additional intermediate buffers.

Comment: Ah, i understand, was doing that anyway. Guess ill just turn off the depth buffer. Thanks.